# Proportional editing going beyond its size and not changing to the defined shape

Tags: proportional-editing

I'm trying to create a round shape at the end of my cylinder, however its not getting the size i want and the round shape i chose.

I chose the sphere shape, i did enable and disabled connected only and nothing. And i tried hiding parts of the shape, so instead of the size being a problem, the thing was that it wasn't changing to the sphere shape i have chosen.

[image]

I'm trying to get this but without the boolean, and its not a screw. I want the roundness end of it.
[image]

Before proportional
[image]

After proportional
[image]

Comment: Sorry, could you be a little more specific about what you're trying to do, and why it's not working? What "edit shape" are you using (ie. smooth, sphere, inverse square, etc..)? Have you checked "connected only"? Have you tried hiding the parts of the mesh you don't want affected?

Comment: Christopher Bennett I chose the sphere shape, i did enable and disabled connected only and nothing. And i tried hiding parts of the shape, so instead of the size being a problem, the thing was that it wasn't changing to the sphere shape i have chosen.

Comment: Hang on a second. So you're saying you want the section of faces you have selected in the first image to come out like a sphere?

Comment: Christopher Bennett If you zoom in the first image ou'll see the size i putted.

Comment: Don't select all the faces, select the very center vertex and try again. Or do you want that end part to stay flat?

Comment: "Don't select all the faces, select the very center vertex and try again."

Oh ya, completely forgot thats how you should do it thanks.